# Crashlytics not deobfusticating code

Tags: proguard, crashlytics, deobfuscation

I'm new to Crashlytics, and I'm having a problem where it is not de-obfusticating my stack traces.  According to Crashlytics this should be happening automatically.  It should be using the mappings.txt file that's included in your .apk to decrypt the stack traces. I have a few questions about the whole process, as well as how I should go about solving the problem.

1) The mappings.txt file should be packaged with .apk by default correct?  I'm using gradle; are there any options that you have to set?

2) I can't seem to download the stacktrace from Crashlytics, nor update the mappings.txt file on their dashboard.  Are either of these options possible?

3) Can I get the stacktraces anywhere else, the application has GSM services enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but it seems to have been fixed by manually reinstalling the Crashlytics plugin.

Instructions at https://www.crashlytics.com/downloads/android-studio

(Using Android Studio 1.0 RC2)

<s>EDIT: Crashlytics is now part of https://fabric.io</s>
EDIT: Fabric is now part of https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/