# Crashlytics doesn't deobfuscate code

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have mysterious problem with Frabric(Crashlytics) service.
I found that crashlytics doesn't de-obfuscate crashlogs automatically.

io.fabric.tools version 1.19.1 and android.tools version 1.2.3 in top-level build file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.1'
}
```

BuildTypes config:

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-coda.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And dependencies:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

The proguard config file contain:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

From gradle console I see tasks related to crashlytics are okay `:app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease` and `:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease`:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
...............................
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesRelease
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectReleaseMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createReleaseMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:retraceReleaseMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease           <=====
:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease          <=====
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease
:app:zipalignRelease
:app:assembleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.569 secs
```

But crash logs are still not de-obfuscated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test exception!!!
       at coda.RootActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:189)     <====
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Are you including the mappings.txt file. Look at this other question for some ideas:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875519/crashlytics-not-deobfusticating-code

Answer (score 1):

I checked one of our projects, we are not using this line in proguard configuration and it's working fine

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```